# Tensorflow bytenet tensor shape mismatch error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use the French-to-English translation implementation given in this link.

https://github.com/buriburisuri/ByteNet

When I run the `train.py` file therein, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\516228\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1021, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\516228\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1003, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\516228\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\516228\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [122,20] rhs shape= [122,40]
     [[Node: save/Assign = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@emb_x"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](emb_x, save/RestoreV2)]]
```

The gist of it seems to be the shape mismatch error. I tried the `restore=False` option in `tf.train`, but to no avail. Can anybody help me figure this out? if I could fix this error somehow, I would be done. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What version of TensorFlow are you using?

Comment: I am using tensorflow 0.12.0

Comment: This doesn't really solve your problem but it is most likely because of the environment you are using (Windows, Python 3.5+).  I doubt the author of ByteNet developed/tested his/her code in such an env.  I ran this on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS/gcc 4.84/python 2.7.6/CUDA 8.0 and it works as intended.

Comment: Yes, you guessed right. I am using python 3.5 on 64 bit windows 7. Hmm, let's see what can be done.